# Unable to prove this language is not context-free using Pumping Lemma

Tags: pumping-lemma

I'm trying to prove that the language { w ϵ {a, b, c}* | n_a(w) < n_b(w) and n_a(w) < n_c(w) } is not a CFL using Pumping Lemma. The symbol "n_a" represents "number of 'a'".

For pumping lemma, z = u(v^i)x(w^i)y, |vxw| <= m, |vw| >= 1.

I've chosen to use the string z = (a^m)b^(m+1)c^(m+1) to show this isn't a CFL.

However, I get stuck on the following case.

Assume 'uvx' represents the (a^m) portion of 'z', 'w' represents the beginning of the (b^m) portion of 'z' and 'y' represents the rest of 'z'.

Now pumping for i = 2, we get z' = u(v^2)x(w^2)y = a^(m + |v|)b^(m + 1 + |w|)c^(m + 1).

Whenever |v| ≠ 0, we see that this isn't in the language, since n_a(z') is not less than n_c(z'). However, for the case where |v| = 0, we get z' = a^(m)b^(m + 1 + |w|)c^(m + 1), which IS in the language. Therefore, pumping with i = 2 would not work. Is this correct?

I tried with other values of 'i', but I'm still not able to prove this language is not a CFL. What am I doing wrong? Is this language actually context-free? Should I be using a completely different 'z' string?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't CFL? Maybe there is a grammar that states that maybe it is indeed context-free? If I find one such, I'll post as an answer

Comment: I think I found one with about 50 transformation rules! One minute while I write it down

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado This question is from an assignment which asks to 'use the Pumping Lemma for CFL's to show that the following language is not Context-Free.' I would assume it's not CF because of the way the question is phrased, but the professor has made mistakes in the assignment questions in the past. I tried building a PDA for the language, but it got a little complex, which further led me to believe it's not CF. Thank you, please let me know if you find something!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: So, 121 transformations for the goal? May it is a little bit repetitive, maybe one can simplify all those rules, but I think I got it right

Comment: @RaymondChen There's a tag in this forum for "pumping-lemma".

Comment: There are many tags for off-topic categories. Still makes them off-topic.

Comment: @IoannisGeorgantas, after all, my answer is wrong... I've tried, but sorry =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `R` be a non-terminal that indicates the following:

> There are no more `a` than there are `b` or `c` in the final product

Stated alternatively:

> For `w ϵ G(R)`, `n_a(w) <= n_b(b)` and `n_a(w) <= n_c(w)`

So the rules for this guy are (let `ϵ` be the empty string):

```
R => ϵ

R => bR
R => Rb
R => cR
R => Rc

R => abcR
R => abRc
R => aRbc
R => Rabc

R => acbR
R => acRb
R => aRcb
R => Racb

R => bacR
R => baRc
R => bRac
R => Rbac

R => bcaR
R => bcRa
R => bRca
R => Rbca

R => cbaR
R => cbRa
R => cRba
R => Rcba

R => cabR
R => caRb
R => cRab
R => Rcab
```

Those 29 are all the possibles transformations that guarantees that any word derived from `R` will have no more `a`s than `b`s and no more `a`s than `c`s.

But the question isn't about `G(R)`, it is stated explicitly that `n_a(w) <= n_b(b)` and `n_a(w) <= n_c(w)`. So, I'll have 3 more non-terminals:

1. `S`, the start point
2. `B`, derived directly or indirectly from `S` and guaranteed to have at least one more `b` than `a` (considering how it"isborn")
3. `C`, derived directly or indirectly from `S` and guaranteed to have at least one more `c` than `a` (considering how it"isborn")

My strategy will be the following:

> Those non-terminals will all be similar to `R`, but they won't have any empty transformation; also, from `S` I'll have a transformation that will generate `bB`, or `Bb`, or `cC`, or `Cc`; from `B`, it is guaranteed to have at least one `b` more than `a`, then it will have a transformation to `cR` or `Rc`; and for `C`, transformation to `bR` or `Rb`

So, this will be my complete grammar, starting with `S`:

```
S => bB
S => Bb
S => cC
S => Cc

S => bS
S => Sb
S => cS
S => Sc

S => abcS
S => abSc
S => aSbc
S => Sabc

S => acbS
S => acSb
S => aScb
S => Sacb

S => bacS
S => baSc
S => bSac
S => Sbac

S => bcaS
S => bcSa
S => bSca
S => Sbca

S => cbaS
S => cbSa
S => cSba
S => Scba

S => cabS
S => caSb
S => cSab
S => Scab

B => cS
B => Sc

B => bB
B => Bb
B => cB
B => Bc

B => abcB
B => abBc
B => aBbc
B => Babc

B => acbB
B => acBb
B => aBcb
B => Bacb

B => bacB
B => baBc
B => bBac
B => Bbac

B => bcaB
B => bcBa
B => bBca
B => Bbca

B => cbaB
B => cbBa
B => cBba
B => Bcba

B => cabB
B => caBb
B => cBab
B => Bcab

C => bR
C => Rb

C => bC
C => Cb
C => cC
C => Cc

C => abcC
C => abCc
C => aCbc
C => Cabc

C => acbC
C => acCb
C => aCcb
C => Cacb

C => bacC
C => baCc
C => bCac
C => Cbac

C => bcaC
C => bcCa
C => bCca
C => Cbca

C => cbaC
C => cbCa
C => cCba
C => Ccba

C => cabC
C => caCb
C => cCab
C => Ccab


R => ϵ

R => bR
R => Rb
R => cR
R => Rc

R => abcR
R => abRc
R => aRbc
R => Rabc

R => acbR
R => acRb
R => aRcb
R => Racb

R => bacR
R => baRc
R => bRac
R => Rbac

R => bcaR
R => bcRa
R => bRca
R => Rbca

R => cbaR
R => cbRa
R => cRba
R => Rcba

R => cabR
R => caRb
R => cRab
R => Rcab
```

Comment: Wow, this seems brilliant. I noticed that you're finding the language for "n_a(w) <= n_b(b) and n_a(w) <= n_c(w)" though, where the signs are "less or equal" instead of "less than". I wonder if this changes much - still trying to understand your method. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I almost turned insane when writing some theorems that relates petri nets to a noncontracting grammar (maintaining history of fired transitions)

Comment: @IoannisGeorgantas, I think I have got it wrong... Could not derive `aabbcc` from `R`, so my assumption for `R` is wrong

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I'm misunderstanding a concept about Pumping Lemma. I will try again tomorrow.